# Conda - import Geopandas error: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I'm trying to import the `Geopandas` module using Python 2.7. Example commands below:

```
conda create --channel conda-forge -n env_test python=2.7 geopandas
# OK

conda activate py27env
python --version
Python 2.7.15

# Import the module now.
python
import geopandas
```

Full error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\envs\env_test\lib\site- 
packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from geopandas.io.file import read_file  # noqa
File "C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\envs\env_test\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", 
line 6, in <module>
import fiona
File "C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\envs\env_test\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", 
line 69, in <module>
from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
File "C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\envs\env_test\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", 
line 9, in <module>
from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator

ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side 
configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line 
sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

Is there way to fix this issue?

Using:
Miniconda 4.12.0

Output of Conda list:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               h099cdad_2    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.11.28       py27h8c360ce_1    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
curl                      7.65.3               h2f83ebf_0    conda-forge
enum34                    1.1.10           py27h8c360ce_1    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.9                h2880e7c_2    conda-forge
fiona                     1.7.13                   py27_0    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5             haa51a25_1002    conda-forge
gdal                      2.2.2            py27h58389d3_1
geopandas                 0.6.3                      py_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.6.2                heec837b_2
hdf4                      4.2.13            ha32470c_1003    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.1                    vc9_2    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2022.1.0          h57928b3_3787    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                h0c8e037_1001    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.7                     vc9_4    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.4               h7fea353_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.65.3               h2f83ebf_0    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.2.2                h75964b3_1
libiconv                  1.15              h0c8e037_1006    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h59e3451_1010    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.4.1.1                  vc9_10    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7a46e7a_0    conda-forge
libpq                     11.5                 h5e4800f_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.8.5                h2880e7c_4    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            he01c9b4_1023    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.2                hd5c6ab6_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h52ad3ab_1002    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h00b1425_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2020.4             hb70f87d_311    conda-forge
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.16.5           py27h0d21db5_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.3.1                hb90df43_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1e               h0c8e037_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.24.2           py27h0e003f4_0    conda-forge
pip                       20.1.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
proj4                     4.9.3                h0c8e037_9    conda-forge
pyproj                    1.9.5.1    py27he834874_1006    conda-forge
python                    2.7.15    h2880e7c_1011_cpython conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                py_0      conda-forge
python_abi                2.7                     1_cp27m    conda-forge
pytz                      2020.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rtree                     0.8.3                    py27_0
setuptools                44.0.0                   py27_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4      py27hc31c106_1000    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.30.1               h0c8e037_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h0c8e037_0    conda-forge
vc                        9                    h2eaa2aa_6
vs2008_runtime            9.0.30729.6161                0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py27_1003    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2             hc56fc5f_1004    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h3cc03e0_1001    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h3cc03e0_1006    conda-forge
zstd                      1.3.3                     vc9_1    conda-forge
```

System OS is Windows Server 2019, but I have also tested on a Windows 10 workstation. Same error occurs when importing Geopandas. The issue is not present when using a newer version of Python, for example Python 3.9.

Comment: I'm not a condo user,  but python 2.7 is dead.  really should be python 3.8+ now

Comment: agreed. you really need to migrate ASAP. Python 2.x end of life was Jan 1, 2020, and no one is maintaining these installers anymore. If you manage to figure this out today, it'll probably be broken again soon as another package falls off the registries. you could try finding a docker image with this built in but if migration is at all an option I'd say go for that.

Comment: Likely need to set some upper bounds on dependencies, like `fiona`, since the recipe wasn't historically very strict about setting version constraints. I'll run a test, but it would be helpful if you provided a `conda list` output in the question body.

Comment: @merv Thanks - I have provided the output of `conda list`